# A Non-end computing loop

Tags: java, cmd, while-loop

This loop seems non-end.
And "sum < 4.7183" seems possible.
The right "k" mist be sent out, the "k" is the minimum possible value of denominator that program makes it's factorial and then the we have the phrase 1/k! and the summation of them with initial value of sum , sum =4.
Really Why?
Where is the problem?

```
//Maybe it's impossibe in short time!    
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.text.*;

public class ConditionalMinK_61 {
    static double j;
    static double f;
    static double sum = 4;

    static int k = 2;

    static String sw;

    public static void SymSymHa() {
        DecimalFormat sa = new DecimalFormat("#.####");

        while(sum < 4.7183) {
            f=1;
            for(j = 1; j <= k; j++)
                f*=j;

            sum+=(1/f);    
            ++k;

            switch(k%8001) {    
                case 0:
                    sw = "|       |";
                    break;

                case 1000:
                    sw = "|L      |";
                    break;

                case 2000:
                    sw = "|LO     |";
                    break;

                case 3000 :
                    sw = "|LOA    |";
                    break;

                case 4000:
                    sw = "|LOAD   |";
                    break;

                case 5000:
                    sw = "|LOADI  |";
                    break;

                case 6000:
                    sw = "|LOADIN |";
                    break;

                case 7000:
                    sw = "|LOADING|";

            }

            System.out.println("Please Wait... S = "+sum+"      "+sw+"  k = "+k+"     Impossible");    
        }    
    }


    public static void Showit() {
        DecimalFormat bs = new DecimalFormat("#.###");    
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "minimum acceptable value of \"K\" is : " + k, "RESULT", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);    
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The war isn't on portability or security... it's on ruining power.", "A Quotation", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        SymSymHa();
        Showit();
    }
}
```

Comment: please format your code... it is hard to read.....

Comment: Can you extract meaningful part of you code and skip all printing funny texts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `k` has reached `171`, the value of `f` becomes so large, it equals `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`. `1/f` is therefore `0.0` and the sum never changes. `sum` increases until it reaches `4.7182818284590455` and then stops increasing, so the `while` loop is infinite.

Try this

```
int k = 171;
double f = 1;
for(int j = 1; j <= k ; j++)
    f*=j;
System.out.println(f);
System.out.println(1/f);
```

The output is

```
Infinity
0.0
```

Even if `double` arithmetic perfectly modeled real numbers, your program would be an infinite loop, because you appear to be attempting to approximate `e + 2`, which is `4.7182818284590...`, so it would never reach `4.7183` anyway.

Comment: Thanks,man. but this problem has a possible output, it's a question of a programming competition.